# How can I detect when iOS ScrollView is at the very top?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

How can I detect when the user scrolled to the very top of my collectionView?

[image: scrolling collection view]

I tried to use this code:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
   if collectionView.contentOffset.y <= collectionView.contentSize.height - collectionView.frame.size.height {
       print("top")
   }
}
```

But it prints "top" even if I didn't get to the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scrollViewDidEndDragging` means the user's finger lifted, but because it has physics to simulate inertia, the view may continue to move.  There is another delegate method for exactly what you are looking for: [scrollViewDidScrollToTop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619382-scrollviewdidscrolltotop) which as the name implies fires when you get to the top of the scrollview.

EDIT:
you can also try:

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
      print("top!")
    }
  }
```

EDIT third time's the charm?  This one only fires once, after the scroll view has stopped moving, if you are at the top.

```
  override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
      print("top!")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay, I tried `scrollViewDidScrollToTop` with a print statement, but when I got to the top it didn't print anything.

Comment: Wierd.  did you try scrollViewDidScroll to see if everything is connected properly? see edit above.

Comment: I believe `scrollViewDidScrollToTop` is only called when you tap the status bar to scroll the scroll view to the very top, not when manually scrolling to the top.

Comment: Yep, the edit works. But, it's printing the "top" message even if the scrollView is not exactly at the top.

Comment: I made one more edit.  if you only car if you are at the top after all motion has stopped use scrollViewDidEndDecelerating.  note that equals means it only fires if you are EXACTLY at the top, but that seems to be what you want.

Comment: You'll probably need to take the scroll view's [`adjustedContentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902259-adjustedcontentinset) into account as well, like `scrollView.contentOffset.y + adjustedContentInset.top == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
     // top
   }
}
```